# How to use pastepecial to paste a chart as bitmap to another sheet in vba

Tags: vba, excel, charts, bitmap, copy-paste

Is there a way to use the pastspecial method to paste a copyied chart as a bitmap to another worksheet. Currently this is my syntax-

```
PasteSheet.PasteSpecial (Format:="Bitmap", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
```

Where PasteSheet is the other worksheet i want to paste to. Currently with this code, it is only pasting in the active sheet. Do i have to use select to copy then select the page i want to paste to, then change back to the sheet I copied from? I hope not as I have a lot of sheets haha.

Thank you

Edit: I have found out that if I Copy the chart as a shape rather than a chartobject I can use the pasteSpecial method to paste to another sheet. That being said it now pastes charts  into one another creating one mega chart haha.

```
GraphSheet.Shapes(chtName).Copy 
PasteSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Office Drawing Object", Link:=False , _
     DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work without needing to activate/select Sheet2:

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture
Sheet2.Paste
```

Comment: The problem is If i want to paste as a bitmap I have to use the pastespecial method, which when in combination with format:=" " doesn't allow for a range or a sheet as a destination.

Comment: `CopyPicture` has a `Format` argument which has bitmap as an option.  You don't need pastespecial, becuase the clipboard already contains an image (not a chart). Try it.

Answer (score 1):

> Do i have to use select to copy then select the page i want to paste
>   to, then change back to the sheet I copied from?

**Yes** - the sheet you paste into must be active. Use `Sheets("mytargetname").Select` - just using `Activate` isn't enough...

If you set

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

your screen won't flash while you do this...

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Its unfortunate that I have to do this but by using bitmap pictures I can make my project work. Also using Application.StatusBar = "text" works great along-side your screenupdating idea. Also Since I just started I'll come back and upvote when I have more reputation

Comment: Yes - I love `.StatusBar` to keep the user informed of what's happening - especially when there is a lot of stuff going on behind the scenes... If you have a lot to do, you can occasionally turn updating on, and off again - it will refresh the screen without "blinking continuously". Good luck building your reputation - "accepting" answers is one way to get some points... :-)

Comment: Oh haha I thought you needed to upvote to accept. Consider your answer accepted, thank you!

Comment: Upvoting is what "others" (or the person asking the question) do to indicate "yeah, that's a good answer". Usually you will do that if someone beat you to it ("I would have said that but you got there first"), or because you recognize an answer is useful. As the person who asked the question, you get to pick "which of these best answered my question" - by "accepting". When others look at your question (because they searched for the same or a similar one), your accepted answer will show up at the top - but others with high upvotes show up too. Often, they are the same thing.