# Excel VBA - Copy a chart and paste as an enhanced metafile

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to copy Chart1 that is an object in Book1 Sheet1 and paste it as an enhanced metafile picture in Book2 Sheet1. I got this code from another site, but it doesn't work:

```
'Book1 and Book2 previously declared as Workbooks and set
Book1.Sheets(1).ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture
Book2.Sheets(1).Range("B3").Paste
```

I get Run-time error 438: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

I would use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327420/vba-excel-paste-chart-as-a-picture), but their code references the chart location and I would like to go by the chart number if possible.

**UPDATE:**

I have revised my code to the following:

```
'Sheet1 and Sheet2 declared and set as Worksheets
Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture
Sheet2.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", _
    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
With Sheet2.Shapes(Sheet2.Shapes.Count)
    .Top = Sheet2.Range("B3").Top
    .Left = Sheet2.Range("B3").Left
End With
```

however it now returns Run-time Error 1004: "Method 'PasteSpecial' of object '_Worksheet' failed".

Comment: Umm, that is strange. It works for me. BTW `'Sheet1 and Sheet2 declared and set as Worksheets` Um, why would you declare them unless you use something like `Sh1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - That is exactly what I'm doing. Next time, I'll call them SheetA and SheetB to lessen the confusion?

Comment: @SMPerron - `Sheet1` in my example code wasn't a variable I'd declared, but the existing default codename of "Sheet1" in the workbook containing the code. By default you can refer to a sheet in the same workbook using either (eg) `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` or just `Sheet1`. Your revised code works for me (but I avoided declaring variables named `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` for reasons outlined above).

Comment: Not sure why it's working for you guys and not me. It works if I change it from `PasteSpecail` to just `Paste`, but the picture quality degrades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture
Sheet1.PasteSpecial _
         Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", _
         Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
With Sheet1.Shapes(Sheet1.Shapes.Count)
    .Top = Sheet1.Range("B3").Top
    .Left = Sheet1.Range("B3").Left
End With
```

Comment: How do you differentiate between Book1 and Book2?

Comment: It doesn't work. Your code pastes a chart rather than a picture, and the pasted chart doesn't match the original. But it does put it in the right place.

Comment: @SMPerron: Change `Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).CopyPicture` to `Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture` as mentioned in this link [How to use pastepecial to paste a chart as bitmap to another sheet in vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801459/how-to-use-pastepecial-to-paste-a-chart-as-bitmap-to-another-sheet-in-vba). See Tim's answer there.

Comment: @Siddharth - I tried your suggested change, but it causes Run-time error 1004 "Method 'PasteSpecial' of object '_Worksheet' failed".